# Access Database Report: Sort Character Field by Numeric Value then Character in 1 field

Tags: ms-access

I am on the final hour of reports and i need them sorted by Tract. They are numbers and letters stored in a character field.

This is how i need them sorted:

1

2 A

2 B

4

5 A

5 B

my current code is IIf([Tract No] Is Null,0,Val([Tract No]))

but it does not sort the charachters

1

2 B

2 A

4

5 C

5 A

Comment: Well, if you want letters to be used, then why are you removing them with Val() function? You will find that 11 will sort before 2.

Comment: Null will always sort before data so no need for 0 substitution. Might want to get acquainted with Nz() function.

Comment: I do most of my stuff in R, new to access for this report

Comment: I did that formula because thats what the microsoft website gave me buit it ignores the Charahcter value on the end

Comment: Yes, it ignores letter because Val() function only returns number from beginning. Don't use Val() and see what happens. In fact, don't use the entire IIf() and see what happens. If you need to make sure 11 sorts before 2, that will require splitting the value into two components - number and letters and using both as sort criteria. Your expression will return the number part but pulling the alpha part will be more complicated assuming the number part can be more than 1 digit.

Comment: Is there actually a space between number and letter in real data?

Comment: yes there is, it is inconsistently sorted when removed

Comment: Correction: so 11 sorts AFTER 2. However, turns out simpler than I thought. Glad you have solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort in two levels:

```
Order By
     Val([Tract No]),
     [Tract No]
```

If *Null* values are present, apply *Nz*:

```
Order By
     Val(Nz([Tract No])),
     [Tract No]
```